# What is locking order of MySQL on query with join statement

Tags: mysql, innodb

When I select for update from join multiple tables, matching rows in all joined tables will be locked.  But I was wondering what is the locking order, which rows are locked first? Is it determined by where table names are in the join statement?

For example, I have two tables. user and department.

```
    | user  | CREATE TABLE `user` 
(  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `department_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `age` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(63) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `department_id` (`department_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 

     department | CREATE TABLE `department` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(63) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(31) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

I have two queries.

```
 explain 
select  user.name as name, user.age as age, department.name as dept_name
    from  user
    INNER JOIN  department  ON user.department_id = department.id
    where  user.status='on'
      AND  department.status='operating'
    order by  user.age
    limit  1 for  update  \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: user
         type: ALL
possible_keys: department_id
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 10
        Extra: Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: department
         type: ALL
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 5
        Extra: Using where; Using join buffer
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)


 explain 
select  user.name as name, user.age as age, department.name as dept_name
    from  user
    INNER JOIN  department  ON user.department_id = department.id
    where  user.status='off'
      AND  department.status='operating'
    order by  user.age
    limit  1 for  update  \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: user
         type: ALL
possible_keys: department_id
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 10
        Extra: Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: department
         type: ALL
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 5
        Extra: Using where; Using join buffer


SELECT user.id as user_id, order.id as order_id, department.id as dept_id 
    FROM user 
        INNER JOIN order ON user.id = order.user_id 
        INNER JOIN department ON department.id = user.department_id 
    WHERE user.age > 30 AND department.name in ('sales') 
    LIMIT 10 FOR UPDATE
```

Not clear about the result of explain. It does not show which rows are locked.

Are rows in table user locked first, and then order and department? Or the matching row locked first?

Comment: *At least* the matching rows will be locked.  You can learn *something* about the order of operations using `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` which will show you how the optimizer has reordered the tables (if it has)... but since this is (arguably) an implementation detail that SQL, theoretically, shields the user from and makes irrelevant... why do you ask?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, the reason I ask is that I recently got a race condition with deadlock. Specifically, there are two transactions of very similar queries, which select and join the same tables, but the where clause is different (e.g., the different department.name in above example). The deadlock dump shows that one transaction holds user lock and waits for department lock while another transaction holds department lock and waits for user lock.  So, I guess the locking order is not by tables, but by the matching records. Maybe DB first locks the matching rows, and then apply gap lock on others.

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAINs` for _both_ queries.

Comment: And provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for all three tables.

Comment: Without an `ORDER BY`, you are getting a random 10 rows; this _may_ be part of the problem.

Comment: What else is going on in the transaction?  Normally queries go so fast that they don't need to Deadlock.

Comment: Let make it simpler, just two tables, and select from their join result. I will update the question.

Comment: @RickJames I have updated the question. My guess is that each transaction will lock the matched rows first and then try to acquire gap lock on other rows, which causes deadlock.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite natural for the Optimizer might pick different query plans for those two queries.  Even if the `EXPLAINs` look similar today, they could be different tomorrow.

Regardless, *you* should plan on deadlocks; it is often futile to try to eliminate all of them.  When you get a deadlock, replay the entire transaction; it is very likely to succeed the second time.

Yes, there can be edge cases where two "independent" queries can collide.  This is *probably* because of edge cases where gap locking collided - or something like that.

There *might* be cryptic clues in `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;`

This index on `user` *might decrease* the frequency of deadlocks:

```
INDEX(status, age)
```

And it is likely to speed up the queries when you have a lot of rows.